# Getting plain HTML/CSS versions of Wordpress themes, no PHP?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

where can I find elegant looking Wordpress (or not Wordpress, but similar style) themes in plain HTML/CSS format, without all the php?

thanks.

Answer (score 6):

View the page source of the theme preview page in your browser. Save the code.

Comment: It goes without saying that this should only be done with themes that one has permission to use!

Answer (score 0):

Easy for one page. Difficult for many pages.
You need to see in browser each page you want to get the HTML/CSS.

```
Firefox Menu > View > View Source
IE Menu > View > Source
```

A good way not only to save but to study the design and HTML/CSS structure,
use `FireBug`, `Firefox` addon. I am very sure it save lots of time and you will love it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean in your question.

If you mean, "Are there themes for Wordpress that don't require php?" then the answer is no. However, you don't actually need to know php in order to use these themes. You can just load them and then alter only the CSS.

If you mean "How can I adapt a Wordpress theme for a non-Wordpress site?" then you'll have to do this yourself, manually. First make sure you are using Firefox and install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). Go to a site that has the theme that you want and then open up Firebug.

Under the HTML tab you'll be able to see the static HTML of the page, after it has been processed by the backend PHP. Just click "Edit" and then copy and paste everything in there into a new file. Then click the "CSS" tab and go through each style sheet, again clicking on Edit in order to copy and paste everything into new files, 1 for each sheet. Then stick all of the files into a folder and edit the header of the html file to make sure the external stylesheet links are pointing to the stylesheets you have created. Open it up in a browser and it should look just as you want it to.